# Italic does not always work

Tags: bug, markdown

I'm not sure if this belongs here, it's a bug report:

*italic* *not italic*

Both expressions above should be drawn italic, but the second doesn't. I know I could work around with

```
*italic not italic*
```

but nevertheless it's unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workaround if you really want to close and reopen italic tag immediately:

*italic* 
*italic* 
*italic* 
*italic*
*not italic ;p*
*italic* (<-note here is a space, but not in precedence to 'not italic')
*italic* 
*italic* 
*italic* 
*italic*

The fact is that there must be a anything between * and * except of *whitespace*. Line break works with precedent *whitespace* as helper but not alone.

Comment: Would you call this a bug? Or is there any specification I didn't read?

Comment: I hardly can say. But I don't think so. The point is, I don't know if any escape sequence exists. If they don't exist there must be some logic when * is a formatting style or just text. And this logic is not easy to implement. So it can be an error but even if I don't think that is the worth to fix it because the issue is untypical. Most times you won't close italic tag and open it immediately again.